# orient-db query composite index using OIndex.get()

Tags: java, orientdb

For a single key index in Orient-DB, I can do something like this.

```
OIndex<?> inx = database.getMetadata().getIndexManager().getIndex("Profile.name");
OIdentifiable luke = inx.get("Luke");
```

Now, how do I query the same index if it has more than one key? Do I need to pass an array, or do I need to pass an arraylist? There is no information about composite keys in the Orient DB manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
index.get(new OCompositeKey(Arrays.asList(key1, key2)));
```